# Android PopupMenu lag + double rendering

Tags: android, submenu, popupmenu

In my activity I have a list of order objects that I would like to display in a PopupMenu which has a SubMenu for each unique customer containing their orders. I'm creating the PopupMenu in OnCreate and a button defined in the XML calls this method to open it:

```
 public void openOrderMenu(View v){
        orderMenu.show();
 }
```

In the emulator it works as expected, I have a PopupMenu of customers, and when clicking a customer a SubMenu containing their orders appears. However on an actual phone, the PopupMenu opens but has an identical PopupMenu sitting behind it, overlapping to one side. There is also a delay when opening the menu and submenus.

Has anyone seen this issue before?

The code for creating the menu is only called once in OnCreate:

```
private void populateOrderMenu(){
    orderMenu = new PopupMenu(this, findViewById(R.id.open_order_menu));
    Menu items = orderMenu.getMenu();
    HashMap<String, SubMenu> customerOrders = new HashMap<>();
    for(Order o : orders){
        String customer = o.getCustomer().getName();
        SubMenu customerSubMenu = customerOrders.get(customer);
        if(customerSubMenu == null){
            customerSubMenu = items.addSubMenu(customer);
            customerOrders.put(customer, customerSubMenu);
        }
        customerSubMenu.add(o.getName());
    }
}
```